# jQuery objects and parameters - using correct terminolgy/explanation

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm posting due to a lack of understanding of a couple of concepts and also to check if my description of this code is accurate.

First I have created parent object called contactForm. I've made this object equal to an object literal which uses literal notation that is, creating a new object with { } and defining properties within the brackets.

Then I have the init method. If you’re familiar with object orientated programming that would be the same things as your constructor method.

Now the next part is where is where I am confused. I am using jQuery to create a new element which are the button tags. Is this newly created element an object inside of the parent object called contactForm?

My second question is am I passing a parameter that sets the text to 'Contact Me!' to the contactForm object or the button element/object?

My final question - is it the case that the parameter passed to the object can also be called a property of that object?

Sorry if I haven't been descriptive enough or accurate enough with my terminology. Any succinct and clearly explained answers would be massively appreciated.

```
var contactForm = {
        init: function() {

            $('<button></button>', {
                text: 'Contact Me!'
            })
                .insertAfter('article:first');
        }
    };
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> First I have created parent object called contactForm. I've made this object equal to an object literal which uses literal notation that is, creating a new object with { } and defining properties within the brackets.

You have an object, which is described in your code by an object [literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Values,_variables,_and_literals#Literals), and assign that to the variable `contactForm`. Not sure why you would call it "parent".

> Then I have the init method. If you’re familiar with object orientated programming that would be the same things as your constructor method.

Your object has a property named "init", which is a function - conveniently this is called "a method". However, constructors in JavaScript work a bit different - every function can construct objects when it is called with the [`new` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new). Of course, a dedicated method to initialize is often used when singleton instances are declared (as literals).

> Now the next part is where is where I am confused. I am using jQuery to create a new element which are the button tags. Is this newly created element an object inside of the parent object called contactForm?

No. What you are doing in the `init` function has (at first) nothing to do with the `contactForm` object. You are calling the [`jQuery`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/) function, and it returns an object on which you call the `insertAfter` method, and as you don't do anything with the result of that function it is garbage-collected.

> My second question is am I passing a parameter that sets the text to 'Contact Me!' to the contactForm object or the button element/object?

You are passing two parameters: a string and an object. What the jQuery function does with these arguments is unknown to your code. According to [the documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery2) (and to the code, if you really wanted to dig in), this will create a `button` element (wrapped in a jQuery instance) and call the `text` method on it.

> My final question - is it the case that the parameter passed to the object can also be called a property of that object?

No. You pass parameters into a function. It might happen that the function sets them as properties of a returned object, but that depends on the function. Anyway they are not called "properties of the function object".

Comment: Thank you for investing your time to help me learn and further my knowledge.